# How to do DetailView in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use DetailView in Grid in Telerik MVC to display another grid when row in main grid is clicked. It works fine. When doing it in Kendo, I create a Client Template in script and add ClientDetailTemplateId in Grid definition to pass parameter. However it fails to display 2nd grid when arrow in rows of main grid is clicked. Here is the code,

```
<%= Html.Kendo().Grid<MaintenanceAthletesSportsInfoViewModel>()
.Name("Sports")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Model(model => model.Id(a => a.ResourceSportId)) 
.ServerOperation(true)
.Create(create => create.Action("InsertAthletesSport", "Maintenance"))
.Read(read => read.Action("AthletesSportsInfoAjax", "Maintenance", new { id = ViewData["resourceId"] }))
.Update(update => update.Action("UpdateAthletesSport", "Maintenance"))
.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteAthletesSport", "Maintenance"))
)
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.ClientDetailTemplateId("BenchmarksTemplate")
.Columns(columns =>
{
...
})
%>

<script id="BenchmarksTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<% Html.Kendo().Grid<MaintenanceAthletesBenchmarkSportsViewModel>()
.Name("Benchmarks_#=ResourceSportId#")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Model(model => model.Id(a => a.BenchmarkResourceId))
.ServerOperation(true)
.Create(create => create.Action("InsertAthletesBenchmark", "Maintenance", new { resourceSportId = "#=ResourceSportId#" }))
.Read(read => read.Action("AthletesBenchmarkSportsAjax", "Maintenance", new { resourceSportId = "#=ResourceSportId#" }))
.Update(update => update.Action("UpdateAthletesBenchmark", "Maintenance", new { resourceSportId = "#=ResourceSportId#" }))
.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteAthletesBenchmark", "Maintenance", new { resourceSportId = "#=ResourceSportId#" }))
)
...
.ToClientTemplate();
%>           
</script>
```

If change "<%" to "<%:" in "script id="BenchmarksTemplate"", then the main grid is not shown. I need help on this. Thanks.

Comment: When you click to open the detail, does it have any console errors?  Your code looks fine so far.

Comment: No error, just can not display the grid in BenchmarksTemplate. In the demo code of Telerik, it only gives @(Html.Kendo.Grid...) which is for Razor. I think it might be a bug in Kendo. I really do not understand why it does DetailView in this way which is deprecated from previous Telerik MVC.

Comment: They do have the ASPX version here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/detailtemplate.  If you still cannot get it to work, I would submit a bug/ticket through your Telerik account.

Comment: After change "<%" to "<%:", second shows up but can not read data (can not go to controller action). I think it is a bug. Please report.